# Sencha 2-0 in xtype: textfield , Ellipsis is not working

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

For text-overflow in Sencha textfield, i needed ellipsis instead of text get clipped, so i added some inline style for the same, but ellipsis is not coming, the text is always clipped , Code is added below for the reference

```
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'First Name',
                name: 'firstName',
                clearIcon: false,
                style: 'white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;',
```

Thanks

Comment: Got it working guys ..  instead of adding inline style i should add "inputCls"  and inside this  just add "white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;"  Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a custom CSS class compiled whit Compass from a SASS source:

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  label: 'First Name',
  name: 'firstName',
  clearIcon: false,
  cls: my-textfield
}
```

in which you could use the SASS specific call to include ellipsis:

```
.my-textfield {
  @include ellipsis;
}
```